# Perl: Finding a File in Directory and Assigning it to a Variable

Tags: perl, file, directory, user-input

I'm trying to develop a perl script that looks through **all** of the user's directories for a particular file name without the user having to specify the entire pathname to the file.

For example, let's say the file of interest was `focus.qseq`. It's located in `/home/path/directory/`. At the command line, normally the user would have to specify the pathname to the file like in order to access it, like so: `/home/path/directory/focus.qseq`.

Instead I want the user just to have to enter `sample.qseq` in the command line, then the perl script will automatically assign the correct file to a variable. If the file is a duplicate but in separate directories, then the terminal will display the full pathname to those files and the user can better specify the file they meant.

I read about the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html#DESCRIPTION) module but it doesn't do quite what I want.

Here's my best attempt at implementing the code as I described above:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $file = shift;

# I want to search from the top down (you know, recursively) so first I look in the home directory
# I believe $ENV{HOME} is the same as $~/home/user
find(\&wanted, @$ENV{HOME}); 
open (FILEIN, $file) or die "couldn't open $file for read: $!\n";
```

I don't really understand how the `wanted` subroutine works in this module. If anyone knows another way to implement the code I describe above, please feel free to make a suggestion. thank you

EDIT:
What if I wanted to utilize the command line option. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $file = '';
GetOptions('filename|f=s' => \$file);

# I believe $ENV{HOME} is the same as $~/home/user
find(\&wanted, @$ENV{HOME});
open (FILEIN, $file) or die "couldn't open $file for read: $!\n";
```

how would the implementation be for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you try to open the file without specifying the path. You need to create another variable, say `$path`. Now, you can pass `\&wanted` as a reference to a subroutine that you write elsewhere, but you might have to resort to global variables. Using a closure would be better.

Your code might look like this then:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my ($file, $path);
GetOptions('filename|f=s' => \$file);

# Set $path when file is found.
my $wanted = sub { $path = $File::Find::name if ($_ eq $file); };

find($wanted, $ENV{HOME});
if (!$path) {
    # complain
}
open (FILEIN, $path) or die "couldn't open $file for read: $!\n";
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at line `my $wanted = sub { $path = $Find::File::name if ($_ eq $file); };`. The terminal is giving me the following error `Name "Find::File::name" used only once: possible typo at wrapper_example.pl line 17.`
`invalid top directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/File/Find.pm line 464.` Do you know what it means by `invalid top directory`?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote `Find::File` instead of `File::Find`. I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: I had it as `File::Find` originally but I was getting the same error so I changed `find($wanted, @$ENV{HOME}.'/');` because I think `/home/user/` is the same as `$ENV{HOME}/`. Now I'm getting permissions errors. it's saying `Can't cd to (/var/spool/postfix/) active: Permission denied at wrapper_example.pl line 19`

Comment: Right. Another edit. `@$ENV{HOME}` is not correct, resulting in an undefined variable, so your script instead looks at the root dir. (In Perl, the sigil (`@`, `$`, `&`) is evaluated before the hash lookup, so it thinks `$ENV` is a reference to an array, which it's not. If you want to find in several directories, just list them in the `find()` routine as a comma-separated list.)

Comment: there's something wrong with how we're setting `$path` in the subroutine. I put a print statement `ERROR!!!` in the `if (!$path)` loop. The terminal is returning that error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15007/discussion-between-cooldood3490-and-gingi)

Answer (score 2):

File::Find should be fine.

you can loop through everything like this

```
find( sub {
    say $File::Find::name if ($_ eq $userInput);
}, '/');
```

that should do what you're trying to do. Don't forget to `chomp` user input, unless it's passed via `@ARGV`

change the `'/'` to whatever directory you want to search in, or you could have the user specify that too.

Comment: what if I wanted to utilize the command line options? so in the command line I would enter `perl script01.pl --filename focus.qseq` Can you explain if the code above would change?

Comment: well if you want to utilize command line options from your perl script, you should use the `Getopt::Long` module; it's documented pretty well. If you want to pass those to the shell you can make a `system()` call or use backticks